# When would I pass in an instance of a class to a method as self?

Tags: python, object, nltk

I am getting started with Python on PyCharm and NLTK and ran into the following question. I have the following code. Text source us a POS-tagged corpus. 'JJ' stands for ADJECTIVE:

**Main Script**:

```
for each_element in textSource[indexCounter:]:
indexCounter += 1

if "JJ" in each_element[1]:                                                        #this is where we check whether the word's POS-tag is JJ
    print("The word we start with: " + str(each_element[0]))
    adj_ant_obj_pair = adjectiveobject.Adjective(each_element[0])                  #Adj object contains two variables. One is iterationSet (synset)
    if adj_ant_obj_pair.iterationSet:                                          #Iteration set is the synset of words we will iterate through
        for each_iternationSet in adj_ant_obj_pair.iterationSet:
            print("The corresponding synset in Wordnet :" + str(each_iternationSet))
            for j in each_iternationSet.lemmas():                              #Isolating each synset and find lemma
                lemmatized_adjective = j.name()
                print("Circling through lematized words inside that Synset " + lemmatized_adjective)          #Parse the adjective word
                if j.antonyms():
                   for each_antonym in j.antonyms():                          #For each antonym (there may be many) we generate a lemmaobject
                        print("Finding the Antonum of that word :" + str(each_antonym))
                        if each_antonym.name():
                            #placeHolderList[j.name()] = each_antonym.name()
                            p = adjectiveobject.Adjective
                            thewordinQuestion = p.getAdjAntPairs(p, lemmatized_adjective, each_antonym)
                            #Here is where we should pass on the lemmaobject to the next stage of the processing process
                            placeHolderList[thewordinQuestion[0]] = thewordinQuestion[1]
                            print(thewordinQuestion)
                        else:pass
                else: print('NO ANTONYM')
    else: pass
else:pass
```

**Class adjectiveobject.Adjective**:

```
class Adjective(object):

    def __init__(self, taggedInput):
        wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
        self.taggedWord = wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(taggedInput,'a') #Ensures that the word in question is an adjective
        self.iterationSet = wn.synsets(self.taggedWord, 'a')             #This is the Synset we need to iteratie through

    def getAdjAntPairs(self, servedname, servedantonym):
        self.lemmaName = servedname
        self.lemmaAntonym = servedantonym.name()
        return(self.lemmaName, self.lemmaAntonym)
```

So here is my question:

The following line of code requires me to pass on the variable containing the class instance into the class.method call like so:

```
thewordinQuestion = p.getAdjAntPairs(p, lemmatized_adjective, each_antonym)
```

If I don't do it [i.e call  p.getAdjAntPairs(lemmatized_adjective, each_antonym)] I get the following error:

```
TypeError: getAdjAntPairs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'servedantonym'
```

Why is that? Shouldn't the call know which instance I would want to pass in by reading the p.getAdhAntPairs command?

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you are missing the brackets in the previous line `p = adjectiveobject.Adjective`. That should fix it, right now, `p` is a `class` object

Comment: you need to do `p = adjectiveobject.Adjective()`. The brackets are important as that will correctly create an instance. As it is you are only taking a reference to the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue appears to be in your main script:

```
p = adjectiveobject.Adjective
```

should be

```
p = adjectiveobject.Adjective(<whatever tagged input should be>)
```

(note the trailing parentheses).  The line you have saves a reference to the *class* itself, whereas what I think you want is an *instance* of the class.

Comment: THXVM CXW and everyone else who commented. I feel a little embarrassed that the response was so straight forward, but I just didn't see it! Made me even more grateful for this answer. Thank you!

Comment: @MNedelko No worries! :)  Glad you're back up and running!

Answer (score 1):

As others already stated, you need to instantiate the class, however, there is another bug (`TypeError`) waiting to go off in the next line. An instance method takes self as an argument but not as a parameter. The reference to the class is automatically passed by python, so you won't need to pass `p` as a parameter in the method `getAdjAntPairs`

```
p = adjectiveobject.Adjective()
thewordinQuestion = p.getAdjAntPairs(lemmatized_adjective, each_antonym)
```

Calling the method like so (with two parameters) is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

> When would I pass in an instance of a class to a method as self?

For typical usage of python, you never need to pass an explicit `self` to a method.

Once you have a class instance, all methods calls will receive `self` as an automatic first argument.

```
foo = Adjective(some_input)  # create instance of the class "Adjective"
foo.some_method()  # "self" is passed implicitly
```

If you for some reason call the class method from the class itself, instead of on a class instance, you have to pass `self`.

This is functionally the same as the previous example:

```
foo = Adjective(some_input)  
Adjective.some_method(foo)  # you must pass "self"
```

If you get an error message complaining about missing arguments, it might be because you forgot to create a instance.

```
baz = Adjective.some_method()  # Error: expected "self"
baz = Adjective().some_method()  # What you meant to do, no "self" needed.
```